# How to send request ibeacon active alarm in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am working for an app with concept of data transfer in ibeacon bluetooth device.

For that i want to know how to start this.,

I am looking for an process as the following:

1. Set Alarm Time
2. List item
3. Read Alarm Time LED control

i want to blink in ibeacon device on LED Control,.

Please feel free to post your answers here.

Thanks in advance.